# How to set up a secure chat using netcat

Tags: security, netcat

I use `netcat` to chat in LAN.

**PC1** listen port 8080

```
$ nc -l -p 8080
```

**PC2** connect to PC1:8080

```
$ nc 192.168.10.1 8080
```

Unfortunately, this is not secure. Anyone sniffing packets can intercept my messages.
How can I chat securely?

Comment: `socat` can be used with `openssl` generated certificates which is likely what you need. Still this is usually more of a hazzle than getting `ssh` tunnels to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html) instead.

> ## Securing Traffic Between two Socat Instances Using SSL
>
> ### Introduction
>
> When you want to connect two socat processes running on different machines and feel that you need to protect the connection against unauthorized access, sniffing, data manipulation etc., you might want to encrypt the communications.
>
> For this purpose socat integrates the OpenSSL library and provides SSL client and server features.

...

Answer (score 2):

SSH would be an easy way. SSH to the machine then use netcat

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just add the --ssl to your syntax.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Common `nc` implementations have no `--ssl` option ([man](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/nc/)), but `ncat` [from the nmap project](https://nmap.org/ncat/) does